# Upload image onto page (in contenteditable div) - preferable with d&d

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, image-uploading

I hope I'm not duplicating any question

I'm trying to implement uploading images into webpage by ajax. I have found (I think nice one) plugin to the jQuery which can handle image uploads:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Now, I have a problem that I really don't know if this plugin can help me with uploads into divs containing any content. Imagine, I have something like similiar:

```
...
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p>This is some example text</p>
</div>
...
```

I would like to simple drag image in and have it displayed on actual cursor position (but basicly after next `</p>` tag). The result should be same like you can upload images into gmail (and are displayed in the text). Of course would be fine to have image displayed in div during uploading, as well (if possible) during dragging (that user will see where he is placing the image). Result should be something like:

```
...
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p>This is some example text</p>
    <div> <!-- containger for HTML validation ->>
        <img src="/uploaded-image.png" />
    </div>
</div>
...
```

Is there any solution how to hnadle this, specially draging image onto **text cursor position**? jQuery-based plugins or pure JS code, both are possible.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has a built-in Drag and Drop and File Reader APIs you can use.

I assume you want to achive something like [this](http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload).

I recommend you read these two articles:

- [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)
- [thebuzzmedia](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/)

Comment: First in German, you are trying me :-D Long time when I have spoken in it. Second article looks helpful - I have working example but I would like to know if it's possible to place image on position of cursor in contenteditable div - that is what I'm missing in there :-(

Comment: You could use [KineticJS](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-an-image-tutorial/), if you haven't already taken it into consideration.